# While generating material component using ng generate am getting couldn't find NgModule error

Tags: angular-material

```
ng generate @angular/material:dashboard <mycomponentname>
```

Getting the below error

[image]

Comment: Issue fixed:Need to run from the project folder i.e parent directory of src

Answer (score 0, accepted):

issue fixed:Need to run from the project folder i.e parent directory of src 
example:
[example solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IdeuO.png)